# Why is a laser used to split a BEC in half?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, bose-einstein-condensate

In a youtube video, a German physicist Wolfgang Ketterle showed that two halves of the condensate creates interference pattern as though they are waves. I paused the video but still unable to understand how the laser cut through the ultra cold atoms that vibrates in lock-step? Do you mean the laser is acting on individual atom but somehow collectively they are waves? What is the role of the laser here can't super thin solid scalpel works as well? The only time he mentioned about laser is for preparing the ultra cold atoms by imparting momentum to slow and I can't find anything in the comment section of that video that explain the cutting part.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AKdmw7Whn0 starts from 25.30 onward

Comment: link the youtube video, indicating the minute at which this statement is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context, the laser here is just to provide a repulsive force. So that you can generate a barrier between two parts of the atomic cloud. If these two clouds were now fully independent (i.e. very high barrier and hence zero tunnelling), once they Bose-Einstein condense they "pick" different phases. Upon removing the barrier, the two condensates mix and they form an interference pattern whose minima/maxima spacing depends on the phase difference.

**Edit**: Now that you've linked the video.

- When he says "green laser", he means a laser of green colour, $\lambda = 532$ nm, which is blue-detuned with respect to the low-lying transition lines of alkali atoms (usually used for BECs). Blue-detuned light results in a repulsive interaction with the atoms.
- This laser is different from the *other* lasers that are used to trap and cool the atoms.
- When he says "turning all the lasers and all the magnetic fields off", he literally means *everything* off. The atoms are just falling due to gravity. Then you shine light again to take a picture.